# Keeping the select query unmodified regardless of the search criteria and parameter changes

Tags: c#, sql, dynamic-queries

I am managing a static class with all the SQL Scripts for DML and Selects.

However, there's a scenario that search can take more than 1 search criteria.

e.g.

```
Select items from table_items where capacity = 10 and type = 'metal'
```

When capacity or type is not mentioned, the query should return all the item,

```
Select items from table_items
```

There are couple combinations here.

1. capacity can be empty input
2. type can be empty input
3. both can be empty input

Does it mean there has to be 3 different SQL queries in my SQL Script static class? And validate each of above combinations over case/if-else? Doesn't make sense to me. Specially that the application is built using data access, entity model separately in a 3-tier architecture.

Perhaps I am totally forgetting the *roots/basics*. I do not want to write dynamic sql queries.

What could be a good work-around for this scenario?

**EDIT: Original query**

```
    public static readonly string SqlGetItemsBy_ID_Capacity_Type = "SELECT TT.[ID], " +
    "TT.[CAPACITY], " +
    "TT.[TYPE], " +                  
    //some code here
                        "FROM [ITEMS]  AS TT " +                    
                        "WHERE //some code here +
    "AND TT.[CAPACITY] = CASE WHEN 0 = @Capacity" + //+ numCapacitySearch.Value +
                        "THEN TT.[CAPACITY] ELSE @Capacity END " + //+ numCapacitySearch.Value +
    "AND TT.[TYPE] = CASE WHEN ??? IS NULL THEN TT.[TYPE] ELSE @Type END" ;
```

Reference to `???` when comparing with NULL...

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: .Net 4.0 C# and SQL Server 2008 (going into 2010).Cheers

Comment: `AND TT.[TYPE] = CASE WHEN " + (DBNull)lstTypeSearch.SelectedItem + " IS NULL " ` Other madness... and there's an error of `IS` is an incorrect syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A case statement where the column is returned if the submitted value is null will give you all rows like this.

```
Select 
  items 
from 
  table_items 
where 1=1 
  and capacity = case when @capvalue is null then capacity else @capvalue end 
  and type = case when @typevalue is null then type else @typevalue end
```

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96bb5/4)

Notice that if you set the values to null, all rows are returned.  If you set a value to say `1`, then only that row is returned.

Comment: I also just about had this with a few `coalesce`s, but ultimately, this worked out cleaner.

Comment: I take my comments back. And this is perfectly the answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so in your query:

```
Select items 
from table_items 
where (capacity <> null or capacity = 10) 
       AND 
      (type <> null or type = 'metal')
```

Or you could do it progmatically with a few `if elses`

And if you are using an ORM like the entity framework. You have dynamic queries and can usually 'build' the query step by step.

Comment: In my scenario, it's isn't a matter about table fields... it's a matter about validating external parameters within the query using a CASE WHEN at its best...